# create widget for each item in the list in Flutter Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am populating an array from json data in Dart

```
 String url="http://someapi.com/words";
    List<Word> words=new List<Word>();
    final res = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "aplication/json"});
    final wordsList = json.decode(res.body);
    for (var h in wordsList) {
      Word word = new Word(title: h['title'].toString());
      words.add(word);
    }
```

This gives me a list of Words. Now how can I use it in the widget? 
Below is the code that I currently have

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final response=fetchWords(); //this response will have list of words
      return new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0,
        horizontal: 15.0),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[ 
          new Row(
            children: <Widget>[ 
             //I want to add a container for each for words here 
            ],
          )
         ])
         );
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter), but I am not sure how to convert the json array into widgets

Answer (score 8):

Use map function.

Example:

```
Row(
  children: words.map<Widget>((word)=>Container(child: Text(word))).toList()
);
```

Comment: Don't forget the .toList() ad the end of the .map<> . Totally oversaw this on the first reading :)

Answer (score 7):

Just use `map` with `toList()`

```
Row(
  children: words.map((word)=> Text(word)).toList()
);
```

`map` will take one word at a time

`=>` is short for `return` so you could have written

```
Row(
   children: words.map((word){
                returnText(word)}
                ).toList()
  );
```

Lastly, `Row` expects a `List` of widgets whereas `map` gives an `Iterable` thus we use `toList()` to get a list of widgets.

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to access the index of element, then

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: words
          .asMap()
          .entries
          .map(
            (e) => Text("${e.value} at index ${e.key}"),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the index in the mapping? for example in react you could do words.map((word, idx) and idx is the index