# Flutter how to do for inside for loop with list widget?

Tags: flutter, android-widget, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

i need to do for inside for loop inside widgets. i create two widgets and i called it form another widget. it says "Not in range 0..6, inclusive:7"

Code :

```
List<Widget> ListMyClips(i) {
    List<Widget> list = new List();
    var lengthItems = widget.data["recommended"][7]["blocks"][i]["items"].length;
    for (var c = 0; c <= lengthItems; i++) {
        list.add(
            ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                child: Image.network(
                    first[widget.data["recommended"][7]["blocks"][i]["items"][c]
                        ["id"]]["image"]["full"],
                    width: 56,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    return list;
}

List <Widget> ListMyWidgets() {
    var lengthBlocks = widget.data["recommended"][7]["blocks"].length;
    List <Widget> list = new List();
    for (var i = 0; i <= lengthBlocks; i++) {
        list.add(ListTile(
            trailing: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight),
            title: Row(
                children: ListMyClips(i),
            ),
        ));
    }
    return list;
}
```

what i need is, dynamically for inside for loop which it will create list of list tiles.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With Dart 2.3 new features, you can use a for inside a collections, to minimize the boilerplate code and make it more legible.

**Before Dart 2.3**

```
Row(
 children: <Widget>[
   europeanCountries
   .map((country) => Text("New $country"))
   .toList();
  ],
)
```

**With Dart 2.3**

```
Row(
 children: <Widget>[
  for (var country in europeanCountries) Text("New ${country.data}")
  ],
)
```

Check more features that could help you in here: [What's new in Dart 2.3](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)

**PS:** Change your functions name to a camelCase form. This way, you should be creating a class instead of a method

Comment: Prefer code snipets instead of pictures. We can copy/edit pictures easily, and it's bad for peoples with bad sight.

Comment: but its only one for loop. is this working with for loop inside for loop ?

Comment: Yes, because it will loop depending on how many "indexes" you'll have. Give it a try, if doesn't work, we'll figure another way out

Comment: check this solution it was easier for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter