# show firestore data array in flutter on buttons

Tags: arrays, database, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want a show three buttons in my flutter app, and its names had on the firestore database array list document,

```
buttons
  0: "country 1"
  1: "country 2"
  2: "country 3"
```

[database like this (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmFNG.png)

[Button arrange like this (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4mFW.png)

I like to use streamBuilder for this,

Source code,

```
class _FrontPageState extends State<FrontPage> {
  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: databaseReference.collection('Collection').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) 
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: specialWidget(snapshot),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  specialWidget(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.map((listItem) {
      return Viewer(
        imagePath: listItem['imageUrl'],
        title: listItem['recipe name'],
        likes: listItem['likes'],
        // buttons: ??,         <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< that is the problem point
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

please help me!

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the code that you currently have.

Comment: update this question, please check it.thank you for your response.

Comment: Please clarify the problem that you are having.

Comment: if your only problem is parsing an array of Strings to List, then you can try listItem['buttons'].cast<String>()

Comment: yes, my problem is parsing an array of String to List, Thank you I trying this.

Comment: thank you all of you ! my problem is solved. help full QnA, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter/50451020