# I am not able to get all the values from the array stored in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount:3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
          var allOptionsForQuestion = List.from(
              masterSnapshot.documents[index]
                  .data['options']);
          for (int option=0; option<allOptionsForQuestion.length;option++) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: Text(allOptionsForQuestion[option].toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),),
              onTap: () {
                **print(allOptionsForQuestion[option].toString());
                print(allOptionsForQuestion.toString());**
              },
            );
          }
        }
      );
    });
```

So I have an array stored in a master document that stores the options for that question. In the two statements bolded, the first statement always prints out the first value while the second statement prints out the entire array. This means that I am accessing it but there is some logical flow error with what I am doing. As of now, all it is showing is the first value 3 times.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan My array only has 3 elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter

Comment: There you go.
Im sorry but I misunderstood your question so I'm gonna remove my first comment.