# Flutter list of Text: How to fix the style of all list items

Tags: list, flutter, object

I am new to flutter and to the concept of Object orientation in general. I am building a list of Text to be used with a CupertinoPicker in flutter, I want to use the same style for all the list items but I don't want to keep repeating the lines and each time specifying the `text style`.
For example, see the list of car `manufacturers` below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TextStyle kStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900);

List<Text> manufacturers = [
    Text('Toyota', style: kStyle,),
    Text('VolksWagen', style: kStyle,),
    Text('Nissan', style: kStyle,),
    Text('Renault', style: kStyle,),
    Text('Mercedes', style: kStyle,),
    Text('BMW', style: kStyle,)
  ];
```

You see the list items in `manufacturers` list can get so long with more cars, can I use a class to tell flutter that my style is fixed to `kstyle` for all the items without explicitly writing `style: kstyle` for every single line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a list to render multiple widgets in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically We can use `DefaultTextStyle` widget

### Final Result

1. CupertinoPicker Widget

[image: used in Cupertino Picker]

2. Common Column Widget

[image: Common Usage]

### 1. The Problem is we need to use CupertinoPicker

which in the library, it is defined as

```dart
    final Widget result = DefaultTextStyle(
      style: CupertinoTheme.of(context).textTheme.pickerTextStyle,
        child: Stack(
```

### 2. Solution : Override Theme

Therefore We are required to defined its style at the very beginning definition of our app

```dart
const TextStyle kStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.blue,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
);

class FlutterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cupertino Picker',
      home: ListViewScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData( // <---------- this
          textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
            pickerTextStyle: kStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### A. Full Working Code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(FlutterApp());
}

const TextStyle kStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.blue,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
);

class FlutterApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cupertino Picker',
      home: ListViewScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData( // <---------- this
          textTheme: CupertinoTextThemeData(
            pickerTextStyle: kStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Text> manufacturers = [
    Text('Toyota'),
    Text('VolksWagen'),
    Text('Nissan'),
    Text('Renault'),
    Text('Mercedes'),
    Text('BMW')
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text("Select Car"),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        child: CupertinoPicker(
          itemExtent: 50,
          onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
            print(index);
          },
          children: manufacturers,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### B. [Optional] Simple use of Default Text Style

```dart
List<Text> manufacturers = [
  Text('Toyota'),
  Text('VolksWagen'),
  Text('Nissan'),
  Text('Renault'),
  Text('Mercedes'),
  Text('BMW')
];

const TextStyle kStyle = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
);

class CarList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: kStyle,
      child: Column(
        children: manufacturers,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new **widget**:

```
class MyTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const MyTextWidget({Key key, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),);
  }
}
```

and use it in your list

```
List<Text> manufacturers = [
    MyTextWidget('Toyota'),
    MyTextWidget('VolksWagen'),
    MyTextWidget('Nissan'),
    MyTextWidget('Renault'),
    MyTextWidget('Mercedes'),
    MyTextWidget('BMW')
  ];
```

If you want to change the **font** in all the application, you must change it from `MaterialApp` like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(
               textTheme: TextTheme(
                //Use the appropriate TextStyle
               ),
            ),);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create one method for all Text widgets:

```dart
Text styledText(String text) => Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900));
```

and use it in your list:

```dart
    List<Text> manufacturers = [
    styledText('Toyota'),
    styledText('VolksWagen'),
    styledText('Nissan'),
    styledText('Renault'),
    styledText('Mercedes'),
    styledText('BMW')
  ];
```

You can also create a list of strings

```dart
    List<String> manufacturers = [
    'Toyota',
    'VolksWagen',
    'Nissan',
    'Renault', 
    'Mercedes', 
    'BMW',
  ];
```

And use tis method when you iterate through your list.

Or you can create a class instead of the method:

```dart
class CustomStyledText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const CustomStyledText(this.text, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  
 
  TextStyle get _style => TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(text, style: _style);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `extension` on the `Text` widget and use that:

1. Create an `extension`:

```dart
// extension 
extension on Text {
  // method to apply style
  applyStyle(TextStyle textStyle) {
    return Text(
      this.data,
      style: textStyle,
    );
  }
}
```

2. Use the `extension` method on the `Text` widget:

```dart
   return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            manufacturers.length,
            // call the applyStyle method on the Text widget
            (index) => manufacturers[index].applyStyle(kStyle),
          ).toList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```