# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

[These are the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8X7n.png)

**Here is my chart.dart file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:udemy_expenses_app/widgets/chart_bar.dart';
import '../models/tanscations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import './chart_bar.dart';

class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> recentTransactions;
  Chart(this.recentTransactions);
  List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
  return List.generate(7, (index) {
   final weekDay = DateTime.now().subtract(
    Duration(
      days: index,
    ),
  );
  double totalSum = 0.0;
  for (var i = 0; i < recentTransactions.length; i++) {
    if (recentTransactions[i].date.day == weekDay.day &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.month == weekDay.month &&
        recentTransactions[i].date.year == weekDay.year) {
      totalSum += recentTransactions[i].amount;
    }
  }

  return {
    'day': DateFormat.E().format(weekDay).substring(0, 1),
    'amount': totalSum,
  };
});
}

double get totalSpending {
  return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
  return sum + item['amount']; 
  //  Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num'.
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    elevation: 6,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Row(
        children: groupedTransactionValues.map((data) {
      return ChartBar(
        data['day'],
        // Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
        data['amount'],
        // Error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
        (data['amount'] as double) / totalSpending,
      );
    }).toList()));
  }
}
```

I dont know where did I go wrong

Comment: btw, this code is from a udemy course. :) I was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The method `groupedTransactionValues` is returning a map of `Object`. Rather, return a map of `dynamic` which is a runtime determined type. Change the line:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
```

to:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> get groupedTransactionValues {
```

Comment: can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777283/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast/67777519#67777519

Comment: Help me with this please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72416961/how-do-you-run-circularprogreessindicator-for-some-time-and-then-display-some-te

Answer (score 5):

Change the object to dynamic in:

```
 (List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues { )
```

If the error is not solved, try adding:

```
 data['day'] as String,
 data['amount'] as double,
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a error:

```
The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Error'.
```

In the example:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (e) {
  yield OnePageLoadFailed(error: e);
}
```

And it gave an error in the catch because the is of type **`Object`**, and my **`OnePageLoadFailed` expects the type `Error`**. So I left it like this:

```
} on Error catch (e) {
  yield OnePageLoadFailed(error: e);
}
```

I hope you can help solve someone's problem, as well as me, especially after the `Null Safety` entry. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
double get totalSpending {
  return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
  return sum + (item['amount'] as double); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is this doing? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
Therefore, you have to change it like the following so it is treated as String and double, respectively.
Instead of

```
return sum + item['amount'];
```

use

```
return sum + (item['amount'] as double);
```

Likewise, instead of

```
data['day']
```

use

```
(data['day'] as String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert

```
List<Map<String, Object>> get groupedTransactionValues {
```

to

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> get groupedTransactionValues {
```

then

```
double get totalSpending {
return groupedTransactionValues.fold(0.0, (sum, item) {
  return sum + double.parse(item['amount']);
});
```

}

parse the item['amount'] to double

It worked perfectly for me!