# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am making a basic shopping app. I am unable to figure out the mistake I made because my IDE didnt show any error

[image: Error]
[image: IDE]

> This is the error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

`var _editedProduct = Product( id: '', title: '', price: 0, description: '', imageUrl: '', );`
var _initvalues = {
'title': '',
'description': '',
'price': '',
'imageUrl': ''
};

```
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);

    super.initState();
  }
```

> I guess this is where it wrong but my IDE didnt show any though.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() { 
    if (_isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as  String;
      if (productId .isNotEmpty) {
        _editedProduct = Provider.of(context)<Products>(context, listen: false);
        _initvalues = {
          'title': _editedProduct.title,
          'description': _editedProduct.description,
          'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageurl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': ''
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: hello , did you find any solution? i have same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I fixed it in my project:

When pushing the named route on tapping the + icon button in the manage your products screen, add an empty arguments string like this:

```
actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                EditProductScreen.routeName,
                arguments: '',
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
```

And by adding an if check to test for an empty id argument since, in order to add a new product, the id is initially set to `''` in the EditProductScreen with this code:

```
class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    price: 0,
    imageUrl: '',
  );
// More code ...
}
```

Then update your `didChangeDependencies(){...}` to look like this:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (isInit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      if (productId.isNotEmpty) {
        _editedProduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId);
      }
      _initValues = {
        'title': _editedProduct.title,
        'description': _editedProduct.description,
        'price': _editedProduct.price.toString(),
        // 'imageUrl': _editedProduct.imageUrl,
        'imageUrl': '',
      };
      _imageUrlController.text = _editedProduct.imageUrl;
    }
    isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Edit: Note that because we now push an empty argument String, the code that validates and saves our product will require an update as tapping the save button makes the program to run funny saving empty products and skipping the validation

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `arguments` is *null*

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
if(args != null) {
  final productId = argument.toString();  // Hoping only string will be there.
  /// Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: am sorry this doesn't seem to be the solution for my prob. Is there any other way

Comment: How are you pushing/calling this screen? With the given information now it is hard to tell where is the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try by making a little change on your last snippet of code.

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments.toString ?? "";
```

Comment: It's better to treat null cases instead of forcing promotion. He could assign `ModalRoute.of(context)` to a local variable and check if it is `null` so it would be promoted by the static flow analysis.

Comment: @Aashar Wahla , you be more specific about what to add in between the quotes

Comment: Aren't there parenthesis missing after the toString call?

Answer (score 0):

```
final productId = modulroute != null ? modulroute.settings.arguments : '';
```

then when and where you use `productId` you use

```
productId.tostring();
```